# property marked as undefined even though it is being used on the same line flawlessly?

Tags: javascript, short-circuiting

in javascript, editing in Visual Studio Code, running on Google Chrome

```
if ((piece == null || piece.color !== us))
```

The above line runs property with no issues, however, when I change it to this:

```
if ((piece == null || piece.color !== us) && piece.color !== UNION)
```

or change this:

```
if (piece.color == null || piece.color == swap_color(us))
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined
```

Why do I get the error in the second case, yet the first case included that same property?

*EDIT*

I've been reading these answers on short circuiting, but it's not clicking, can someone help me form a boolean expression?
Basically, piece.color could be one of three cases

- null
- us
- them (which is the same as swap_color(us)
- UNION

I want to run

```
continue;
```

in situations when 
`(piece.color == null || piece.color == swap_color(us))`
and when `piece.color !== UNION`

Hence my erroneous first attempt

Comment: One way to think about it: if you remove the or from the condition, it reads: `if (piece == null && piece.color !== UNION)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do I get the error in the second case, yet the first case included that same property?

Boolean operators are [short circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). That means for

- `a || b`: `b` is only evaluated if `a` is `false`
- `a && b`: `b` is only evaluated if `a` is `true`

So, `piece.color !== us` is *only* executed if `piece == null` is `false`, i.e. `piece` is not `null` or `undefined`. That means accessing `piece.color` will always "work" (it won't throw an error).

On the other hand, `piece.color !== UNION` is executed if `piece == null` is `true`. What you wrote basically means "if `piece` is null and `piece.color` is not `UNION`. That doesn't make much sense though (because `piece` being `null` implies that `piece.color` doesn't exist).

---

> I want to run `continue;` in situations when  `(piece.color == null || piece.color == swap_color(us))` and when `piece.color !== UNION`

The "and" in this sentence translates to a boolean OR. But you still have to check that `piece` is not `null` and you can simplify the the expression because `piece.color !== UNION` implies `piece.color == swap_color(us)`.

```
if (piece == null || piece.color !== UNION) {
  continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `piece` is null then `piece == null || piece.color !== us))` will be true without checking `piece.color !== us`, so `piece.color !== UNION` will be evaluated but because `piece` is null `piece.color` is undefined.

Your logic is faulty in this way. So faulty in fact that I'm not sure what you mean. It would seem that you mean; what do you want to happen if `piece` is null?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of something called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation):

Let's assume `piece == null`: in the first case, the compiler only needs to evaluate the left side of the `or`. Upon getting `true`, it can skip the right side, since the entire expression will be `true` anyway.

In the second case, the left expression evaluates to `true` like above, but then the compiler attempts to evaluate the right side, since an `and` demands both sides to be `true`. That's where it encounters the non-existing property.

Try this:

```
if (piece === null || (piece && piece.color && piece.color !== us && piece.color !== UNION)
```